# Unit testing flask errorhandler

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am trying to unit test my Flask app's [errorhandler](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#registering), which looks something like this:

```py
from http.client import INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

bp = flask.Blueprint('my_app', __name__, url_prefix='/my_app')

@bp.route('/get_metadata', methods=['GET'])
def get_metadata():
    raise CustomException("custom message")

@bp.errorhandler(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
def handle_exception(e):
    response = flask.make_response()
    response.status_code = 500
    # custom stuff here
    return response
```

This code works fine for my actual application - the CustomException is raised, caught by the errorhandler, processed, and then returned as a 500 response.

For my unit test, I have something like this:

```py
class AppTests(parameterized.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.flask_app = app.create_flask_app('localhost:5000', 'localhost:3000')


    @parameterized.named_parameters(('failed_server_call', 500))
    def test_get_branch_metadata_endpoint(self, expected_status_code):
        with self.flask_app.test_client() as client:
            response = client.get('/my_app/get_metadata')
            self.assertEqual(expected_status_code, response.status_code)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        absltest.main()
```

Lots of implementation omitted, but I think those are the relevant portions.  In the unit testing context, the CustomException is raised, but not handled by the @errorhandler (in fact, the @errorhandler is never invoked at all), and the test basically just errors out because of the unhandled exception.  My expectation is that the "fake" flask client (from `test_client()` should behave exactly like the real client, and correctly invoke the @errorhandler without any additional work from me.

For background, we are still using `Flask 1.4` (Upgrade coming soon(tm)) and `absl.py 1.3`.  Tests are executed using `bazel test`, `Bazel 6.4`.  `Python 3.10.9`.  I am something of a Python newbie, so unsure what else might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you didn't set propagate errors?

Something like this:

```
    def setup(self):
        self.flask_app = app.create_flask_app('localhost:5000', 'localhost:3000')
        self.flask_app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
```

This causes exceptions to propagate up to your exception handlers.